# How to call a function X number of times at the same time without one interrupting the other?

Tags: c#, function, unity-game-engine, methods

Lets say i have this function:

```
int num;

void aa()
{
  num=0;
  //Wait 1 sec
  num++;
  //Print ("num= "+num ..
  //Wait 1 sec
  num++;
  //Print ("num= "+num ..
}
```

if i call aa() two times at the same time i get:

```
num=1 from first time called
num=2 from second time called
num=3 from first time called
num=4 from second time called
```

but i want the result to be

```
num=1 from first time called
num=1 from second time called
num=2 from first time called
num=2 from second time called
```

So i want multiple instances of a function but none interrupt or mix with the other.

note: I am using Unity and C#.

Comment: Sounds like you need `num` to be a local variable within `aa` instead of a field... Or call `aa` on different objects. We can't say more than that without more information.

Comment: sounds like you need instances....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void aa()
{
  int num;
  num=0;
  num++;
  num++;
}
```

As per Jon Skeet's comment on your OP.